# Drop-down list appears even though my cursor isn't hovering above it

Tags: html, css

My drop-down list should only appear once I hover over the "Text-generative AI" button. However, once I move my cursor anywhere along the button's left side, the drop down list appears.

Here's the code:

*HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">

    <head>
        <title>Productivity Tools</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>TECH TEAM <img src = "imgs/ebmnhs_logo.jpg" style = "position:relative; left:1200px;" height = "50"></h1>
        <hr>

        <div class = "dropdown">
            <button>Text-generative AI</button>
            <div class = "content">
                <a href = "https://chat.openai.com/" target = _blank>ChatGPT</a>
                <a href = "https://bard.google.com/" target = _blank>Bard</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*CSS

```
.dropdown button{
    background-color: darkgrey; /* button color */
    color: white; /* font color */
    padding: 10px 10px; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* .dropdown:hover button{
    background-color: grey;
} */

.dropdown a{
    display: block;
    color: black; /* font color */
    text-decoration: none; /* to remove underline */
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .content{
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-width: 90px;
}

.dropdown:hover .content{
    display: block;
}
```

This is what my drop-down button looks like when not interacted with:
[image]

Its list should only appear when my cursor is hovering above it like this:
[image]

And its shouldn't appear when my cursor is hovering above it like this:
[image]

Or this:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Change the `.dropdown:hover .content` selector into `.dropdown button:hover + .content`, and done.

Answer (score 1):

Your list appeared was because of parent container's width is full width of the view port. That's why when you hover the place outside the button the list appeared.
[image]

You could try to set the parent width to the content width;

```css
.dropdown button{
    background-color: darkgrey; /* button color */
    color: white; /* font color */
    padding: 10px 10px; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* .dropdown:hover button{
    background-color: grey;
} */

.dropdown a{
    display: block;
    color: black; /* font color */
    text-decoration: none; /* to remove underline */
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .content{
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-width: 90px;
}

.dropdown:hover .content{
    display: block;
}

.dropdown{
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">

    <head>
        <title>Productivity Tools</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>TECH TEAM <img src = "imgs/ebmnhs_logo.jpg" style = "position:relative; left:1200px;" height = "50"></h1>
        <hr>

        <div class = "dropdown">
            <button>Text-generative AI</button>
            <div class = "content">
                <a href = "https://chat.openai.com/" target = _blank>ChatGPT</a>
                <a href = "https://bard.google.com/" target = _blank>Bard</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `onMouseOver/onMouseEnter` for opening and for closing: `onMouseLeft` eventListener

if you want to do it with only css
do

```
body:hover .dropdown-menu{
  // your closing css here
}
```